# how to send packet many client differently time c#

Tags: c#, networking

I have a question, about Network send packet.

I send packet many client. example, Client A, B, C I have.(It is actually more than 40.)

I send packet to client A, B, C at the same time, and after 40sec I send  packet B and C, delay 20sec client A.

When the number of clients is small I use background worker number of client.

Synchronize when each client receives a packet, but my method is bends the rules.

Um...Is there a way to use a background worker or other thread?

Comment: That is what multicast is for.

Comment: @RonMaupin Oh Thank you!! I try it!!